# How to redirect to users/:id after successful devise sign in - rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Devise 2 is really awesome! However, I have been trying superhard to get it to redirect to users/:id after sign in.

The default page is root after user successfully sign into the site. However, I want it to go to the users/:id page that is controlled by users_controller.rb. After sign in, I can manually enter localhost:3000/users/1 to go to the user profile page where I can access the user information, so the show controller is working fine.

The key question is how to I get the site to go to localhost:3000/users/1 after user 1 signs in.

I read the devise wikis many times and googled a lot. The simplest way is to override devise by adding in application_controller.rb:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  dashboard_path
end
```

I guess my question is how to define the dashboard_path? What do I add in config/routes.rb and in application_controller.rb?

Any help is greatly appreciated! I am using devise 2.0 and rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First see [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) link

I tell you what I do
**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users,:has_many => :comments, :controllers => {:sessions => devise/sessions', :registrations => 'devise/registrations'} do       

       match '/users/:id/dashboard', :to => "users#dashboard", :as => :dashboard
```

Then declare following helpers in your helper.rb file when you use devise keywords
**UsersHelper**

```
 def resource_name     
     :user    
 end    

 def resource     
    @resource ||= User.new     
  end     

  def devise_mapping     
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]      
  end      

 end
```

**Application_controller.rb**

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)    
     if current_user.admin?     
      stored_location_for(resource) || admin_path     
    else       
       stored_location_for(resource) || dashboard_path(current_user.id)      
     end       
  end
```

I hope this would help you.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Urjit! Interestingly, if I just `add def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)  @user=current user end` it also redirects to users/:id after logging in. I didn't need to add anything else to the route.rb